# How to reference a specific view in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I know how to access a listview item through an onitemclicklistener but how do I do something like change the background color in code.

sudo code:

```
lv[0].setBackgroundResource(R.color.red); //change the background of the first listview item
```

Is there a way to access each view of the listview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Matt: It's not that it's weak, you just have to understand the way it works.

Yellavon, at any given time, your ListView only contains the visible items, so you can't access and change items directly. As they scroll out of view, the views are recycled, and populated with data by the ListAdapter. It's within this adapter that you need to handle the cases where items should differ. If you've created your own custom ListAdapter (e.g. ArrayAdapter, BaseAdapter), in your `getView()` method, simply add some logic within to handle the cases in which the background color should change.

Let's say for example, you have a list of integers, and you want any integer >= 50 to show up in red:

```
if(items.get(position) >= 50) {
    myView.setBackgroundColor("#FF0000");
} else {
    myView.setBackgroundColor("#000000");
}
```

(It's important to make sure to handle the else cases, as you may get a recycled view of an item that had been colored red. In this case, you'd have to reset it to whatever default background color you need.)

If you've never built a custom adapter, [this excerpt from CommonsWare's book](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) on creating custom ListAdapters is a great resource.

EDIT: Further thought, based on your comment:

In your custom ExpandableListAdapter

```
private Object lastSelectedObject;

public void setLastSelectedObject(Object obj) {
    lastSelectedObject = obj;
}

public Object getLastSelectedObject() {
    return lastSelectedObject;
}
```

Implement `onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id)` in your ListActivity

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
    ((CustomAdapter)l.getAdapter()).setLastSelectedObject(items.get(pos));
}
```

Now, back in `getView()`

```
Object obj = getLastSelectedObject();
if(obj != null) {
    //handle background switching for your View here
} else {
    //reset background to default for recycled views
}
```

Comment: I have a custom listadapter (It's actually a custom `expandableListAdapter`) I have a `getChildView` that receives the `groupPosition`, `childPosition`, `convertView` and `parentView`. The problem is I need to change the background based on the last child view that was clicked. Can I stick some kind of `onclicklistener` in this method? Also, how do I store which view was clicked? Thanks.

Comment: Ah I see. I've added some additional suggestions for you. Basically, add a private variable to your ListAdapter to keep track of the last item clicked (just substitute whatever your item class type is for `Object`). Then, whenever an item is clicked, set that as your last selected item. Then in your `getView()`, retrieve the object, and handle your logic based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List13.html)

```
int first = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
int count = view.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
   TextView t = (TextView)view.getChildAt(i);
   if (t.getTag() != null) {
      t.setText(mStrings[first + i]);
      t.setTag(null);
   }
}
```

Seems like getChildAt is the method you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

The ListView class in android is weak.

The short answer to your question is no, not easily.

Someone asked about it at the Google I/O and the answer from the android team was to use a vertically filling LinearLayout and just add a stack of child views into it (which basically gives it the same functionality as a ListView).

You can do getChild(x) to get any of the views